# Powershell shell to other application with parameters

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling with powershell trying to get an external command to run

```
$im_convert_exe = "convert.exe"
$srcname = "C:\Scan\input\Test_*.tiff"
$destname = "C:\Scan\merged\ScansMerge.tiff"

$cmdline =  $im_convert_exe + " `"" + $srcname + "`"" + " `"" + $destname + "`""
echo $cmdline
invoke-expression -command $cmdline
```

I'm trying to use imagemagiks's convert tool to convert a folder of tiff files into one multipage tiff, but i keep getting an invalid parameter error. I cant see what i'm doing wrong, but i'm sure its to do with quotes or something being in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use ordinar invoke operator:

```powershell
& $im_convert_exe $srcname $destname
```

PowerShell will even add double quotes itself when calling the program.

NOTE: By the way, your error may be connected with your use of the asterisk character `*`. I think Imagemagick expect your shell to expand asterisk and will not expand it on it's own. So you maybe really want to do this:

```powershell
$im_convert_exe = "convert.exe"
$srcnames = ls "C:\Scan\input\Test_*.tiff"
$destname = "C:\Scan\merged\ScansMerge.tiff"

& $im_convert_exe $srcnames $destname
```

Comment: I kind of stumbled upon this myself, i think i was trying to make it more complex than it needed to be

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```powershell
$im_convert_exe = "convert.exe"
$srcname = "C:\Scan\input\Test_*.tiff"
$destname = "C:\Scan\merged\ScansMerge.tiff"

$cmdline = [scriptblock]::Create($im_convert_exe + " `"" + $srcname + "`"" + " `"" + $destname + "`"")
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $cmdline
```

It is also a good idea to specify a full path to the executable.